# Dataframe create new column based on other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame('a'=c(1,2,3,4,5), 'b'=c(1,20,3,4,50))
df
    a    b
1   1    1
2   2   20
3   3    3
4   4    4
5   5   50
```

and I want to create a new column based on existing columns. Something like this:

```
if (df[['a']] == df[['b']]) {
  df[['c']] <- df[['a']] + df[['b']]
} else {
  df[['c']] <- df[['b']] - df[['a']]
}
```

The problem is that the `if` condition is checked only for the first row... If I create a function from the above `if` statement then I use `apply()` (or `mapply()`...), it is the same.

In Python/pandas I can use this:

```
df['c'] = df[['a', 'b']].apply(lambda x: x['a'] + x['b'] if (x['a'] == x['b']) \
    else x['b'] - x['a'], axis=1)
```

I want something similar in R. So the result should look like this:

```
    a    b    c
1   1    1    2
2   2   20   18
3   3    3    6
4   4    4    8
5   5   50   45
```

Comment: The problem is that when using == as logical operator that indeed only one, respectively the first entry is selected. The vectorized answer by @akrun should do the job.

Comment: Technically, you could also use somthing like `with(df, (a * c(-1L, 1L)[(a == b) +1L]) + b)` but it's not very intuitive

Answer (score 34, accepted):

One option is `ifelse` which is vectorized version of `if/else`.  If we are doing this for each row, the `if/else` as showed in the OP's pandas post can be done in either a `for` loop or `lapply/sapply`, but that would be inefficient in `R`.

```
df <- transform(df, c= ifelse(a==b, a+b, b-a))
df
#  a  b  c
#1 1  1  2
#2 2 20 18
#3 3  3  6
#4 4  4  8
#5 5 50 45
```

---

This can be otherwise written as

```
df$c <- with(df, ifelse(a==b, a+b, b-a))
```

to create the 'c' column in the original dataset

---

As the OP wants a similar option in `R` using `if/else`

```
df$c <- apply(df, 1, FUN = function(x) if(x[1]==x[2]) x[1]+x[2] else x[2]-x[1])
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please give an `apply()` (or `sapply()`, `mapply()`, `tapply()`, `lapply()`) version as well if it is possible (or a link with basic examples)? I want to understand their mechanism with this simple example (I have to `apply` more complex functions and conditions). Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @ragesz If you want to understand where to use these functions, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega) could help you.

Comment: @ragesz When vectorized solutions are available, using slow `apply()` loops is a bad idea. One should not seek to use [a specific type of command to solve a problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Instead it is important to learn which methods are suitable in which cases. The vectorized solutions in this answer show the correct way to solve the problem in R.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a slightly more confusing algebraic method:

```
df$c <- with(df, b + ((-1)^((a==b)+1) * a))

df
  a  b  c
1 1  1  2
2 2 20 18
3 3  3  6
4 4  4  8
5 5 50 45
```

The idea is that the "minus" operator is turned on or off based on the test `a==b`.

Comment: It's very nice, thank you! Actually the point of my question was on "creating new column based on existing ones", and I just created a simple basic example to demonstrate this problem. But you solution is very intuitive, I can understand R a bit more (how R converts boolean to integer automatically etc.

Answer (score 8):

If you want an apply method, then another way with `mapply` would be create a function and apply it,

```
fun1 <- function(x, y) if (x == y) {x + y} else {y-x}
df$c <- mapply(fun1, df$a, df$b)
df
#  a  b  c
#1 1  1  2
#2 2 20 18
#3 3  3  6
#4 4  4  8
#5 5 50 45
```

Answer (score 7):

Using dplyr package:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(c = if_else(a == b, a + b, b - a))

df
#   a  b  c
# 1 1  1  2
# 2 2 20 18
# 3 3  3  6
# 4 4  4  8
# 5 5 50 45
```

Comment: Could you provide info w.r.t performance vs., say, @akrun's answer?

Comment: @hello_there_andy feel free to test and edit this post.

Answer (score 4):

A solution with `apply`

```
myFunction <- function(x){
  a <- x[1]
  b <- x[2]
  #further values ignored (if there are more than 2 columns)
  value <- if(a==b) a + b else b - a
  #or more complicated stuff
  return(value)
}

df$c <- apply(df, 1, myFunction)
```