# Make data frame with for loop in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I need make a for loop like this df, when I can put certain rule like this:

```
Rack = 48, all rows
profundidad = 1 to 13, in all nivel.
nivel = A to E, put  in _enable_  **Y**
nivel = F to L, put in _enable_ **N**
enable = Y and N
```

Im want have this data frame

[image]

Because I need change the input value with other Rack, profundidad and nivel.

Maybe for loop not is necessary. Im try with `dplyr`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unique combination of all elements from two (or more) vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388359/unique-combination-of-all-elements-from-two-or-more-vectors)

Comment: For setting the value of `Enable`, this should answer your question: [Dataframe create new column based on other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39165340/8366499)